# Remove rows if they begin with a duplicate value

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

Let's say I have a spreadsheet with a list of client shipments and the shipment numbers. For example, `DairyQueen 024918`. Each shipment number is six digits. This list of shipments gets added onto throughout the day. At the end of the day, we want to see the most recent shipment for each company.

Basically, I want to remove the rows that have duplicate client names, but not duplicate client shipments, and only keep the most recent, so the one on the bottom of the list. It's not possible to put the client and shipment number in separate columns, due to a specific setup of data retrieval from another system.

Here's an example:

```
Costco 002456
DairyQueen 001239
Costco 001335
DairyQueen 008448
Menards 001444
Menards 002448
```

I'd want to be left with this list:

```
Costco 001335
DairyQueen 008448
Menards 002448
```

The code I've tried so far is as follows:

```
Sub DeleteOldClients()
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    LastRow = Range("A1").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        For j = 1 To LastRow
            If (Left(Range("A" & i).Value, Len(Range("A" & i).Value) - 7) = Left(Range("A" & j).Value, Len(Range("A" & j).Value) - 7)) Then
                Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Delete
                LastRow = LastRow - 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, it fails. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: How does it fail? Does it give you an error? What does it do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop counters (`i` and `j`) were not set correctly, `j` should always start at `i + 1`, and `i` must end at `LastRow - 1`. You should also delete the row using `j`. I have also made the conditional statement a bit more simple. Please mark the question as answered if my reply works for you.

```
Sub DeleteOldClients()
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    LastRow = Range("A1").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    For i = 1 To LastRow - 1
        For j = i + 1 To LastRow
            If Range("A" & i).Value = Range("A" & j).Value Or Mid(Range("A" & i).Value, 1, 4) = Mid(Range("A" & j).Value, 1, 4) Then
                Range("A" & j).EntireRow.Delete
                LastRow = LastRow - 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! The only problem was that deleting with row "j" made it delete the NEWER shipments, which were at the bottom, when I wanted it to delete the OLDER shipments, which were at the top. I just switched it to deleting row "i" instead, and now it works great!